# What is the word for a tree that loops back on itself?

Tags: math, graph

Compare these graphs :

```
A -> B -> C

A -> B -> C -> A
```

What would a graph like the lower one be called so I can google it?

Graph that loops around?

Comment: Of course, a "tree" that loops back on itself is not a tree, according to the definition of a tree.

Comment: You might want to google the terms "directed acyclic graph" and "directed cycle graph". It's not clear from the question whether you're only interested in simple cycles, or in more complicated graphs involving some cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular Linked list, You could also check on the wiki, and under section Circular Linked List
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Not really the same thing: a tree is much more general than a list, so there are many possible interpretations of a "tree that loops back on itself" beyond the simple directed cycle underlying a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

you call such graph `Eulerian Cycle` or `Eulerian circuit`.

Comment: No, that's a different notion. "Eulerian Cycle" doesn't describe a property of the graph itself; it describes a particular kind of path within an existing graph. "Eulerian Graph" would be a valid answer, but I doubt it's what the OP wants.